# CollapsingToolbar not Collapsing through ViewPager ..?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, vertical-scrolling

> My XML Layout is like this:

```
<DrawerLayout>

             <CoordinatorLayout>

                          <AppBarLayout>

                                 <CoolapsingToolbarLayout>
```

> ViewPager is having an Char nothing Special

```
                                          <ViewPager>
                                       ---------------
                                          </ViewPager

                                          <Toolbar>
                                       ---------------
                                          </Toolbar>


                                </CoolapsingToolbarLayout>


                            </AppBarLayout>
```

> RecyclerView is having layout behavior: "app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

```
                      <RecyclerView>
                   -------------------
                   -------------------
                   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior

                      </RecyclerView>


               <FloatingActionButton>
               ----------------------
               ----------------------
               </FloatingActionButton>


         </CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Fragment for NavigationDrawer

```
     <fragment------
  --------------/>

 </DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here's the layout code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/home_drawer"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.androidforfun.divyam.homie.main_app.HomeActivity"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="325dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="7dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/main_viewpager"
                android:tag="main_pager"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="7dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_fragment"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.androidforfun.divyam.homie.fragments.NavDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_nav_drawer" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some scroll flags to your CollapsingToolbarLayout such as:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

Comment: ok try these: 1) Clean the project and build it, this sometimes works for me. 2) Try removing the view pager. 3) Try using a NestedScrollView instead of a RecyclerView, just for testing purposes.

Comment: tried that to didn't worked..?? do you know what's the problem , i think it's because DrawerLayout is parent and and cause of that CoordinatorLayout is not functioning properly..

Comment: No I don't think that's the problem, DrawerLayout can be parent of CoordinatorLayout without any problems. I have that in my app

Comment: Please post the full layout

Comment: but i've seen in my blogs they say that it's important to always make Coordinator Layout your parent Layout..

Comment: but i've seen in many blogs they say that it's important to always make Coordinator Layout your parent Layout..

Comment: CoordinatorLayout is already parent of every element that is supposed to be its child. Your structure is fine. Please edit the question with the full layout so debugging can be easier

Comment: i've posted the full code of the layout.. please check this out